# SQL Server Indexes for multiple searchable fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, database-performance

I have a table in a SQL Server 2012 SP1 database which has around a dozen columns that are all searchable. The user using the application can search by one or multiple columns depending upon their needs, with a SQL statement created at runtime.

Because of this, we've setup a dozen indexes, one for each searchable column.  We have *not* included the other columns in the index, since having 12 copies of the same data in each index just seems wrong (and the DBAs keep whining about disk space).

Unfortunately, this leads to a lot of RID/Key lookups, since not one single index covers any query that's executed (the queries run by searches on the application return about 20 of the columns in the table, including the dozen which are searchable).

The table has around 30 million rows to it, but a normal search only returns anywhere from 1-1,500 rows, so the problem isn't (yet) horrible, I'm just trying to be proactive.

So, to try to avoid as many RID/Key lookups as I can, what would be another way to index this table?  One index with all the searchable columns doesn't help, since an index isn't used unless the first column is one of the criteria.

Comment: Not much in the way of detail here. I have no idea how you are building your search queries but you might want to take a look at this article which covers this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Find the **most likely** search parameter and try to optimize for those 2, 3 combinations of parameter that are most likely to be used. You cannot optimize for any combination of possible parameters - pick those that are most likely to be used and make those fast.

Comment: @SeanLange: the fields/values differ, but it's effectively SELECT x,y,z FROM table WHERE a=b AND c=d.  Generally, nothing with an IN or subquery or anything fancy; just simple equality.  Will take a look at your link, too.

Comment: @marc_s: Unfortunately, there is a very wide variety of searches on the table. No 80/20 rule here. After some analysis, the 10 most popular patterns of parameters (give or take) only accounted for about 25% of searches

Comment: If you are doing all equality searching, you might benefit from a full text index.

Comment: My recommendation would be that if you aren't having any issues right now, then adding new indexes to a 30 million row table is asking for trouble.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Not all the columns are character data, unfortunately, so it wouldn't be of great benefit.  I would also hope to do something with drastically altering how queries are structured, since multiple applications by multiple owners would need make changes.